# How can accessibility settings be configured from inside an XCTestCase

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uiaccessibility, xctestcase

Button Shapes (the accessibility feature) on iOS can be enabled and disabled from the setting app on the simulator. But what if we want to enable and disable it to take snapshots or any other kind of unit test from within `XCTestCase`?

It doesn't seem to be a UITrait and has a `buttonShapesEnabled` property exposed from `UIAccessibility` but how do we change this property from inside a unit test?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a UI Test to do this.

Using a UI Test, you could open the settings app and configure this setting by creating an XCUIApplication that targets the Settings app.

```
XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
```

Then interact with the buttons in Settings to enable/disable button shapes.

You could then launch and interact with your app, using the screenshot() method to take screenshots:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiscreenshotproviding/2897250-screenshot